# A scrolling fixed height div in bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Newbie to Css so hoping this is trivial.

Assume I have a two column, responsive bootstrap 3 grid.  In the left column, I want the column to always fill the height of the browser window, but then within that column I then want a scrollable div to serve up content that is a list much longer than the height of the column it is embedded in.

Make sense?  So far my experiments lead me to the longer div defining the height of its container, which means the entire window scrolls vertically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="
      height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
    ">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250" alt="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```